# Change only the text of the button of my Confirm Service when first called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dialog

I have a Confirm Service that opens a MatDialog when is called, showing the buttons **YES** or **NO** and returns *true* or *false* depending of the answer.
My problem is that when I to call this Confirm Service for the fist time, I want the text of the buttons be something like **"Delete All"** and **"Delete One"** instead of **YES** and **NO**. And then after the first call of this Service, depending of the answer (let's say Delete All), it will be called again but with the normal text of **YES** and **NO** for confirmation.

I tried to created another Service similar to this one changing only the text of the buttons, but it does not seems right to have all of this copied only for that.
Here's my code.
**CONFIRM.COMPONENT.HTML**

```
<h1 matDialogTitle class="mb-05">{{ data.title }}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content class="mb-1">{{ data.message }}</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">YES</button>
    &nbsp;
    <span fxFlex></span>
    <button type="button" color="secondary" mat-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close(false)">NO</button>
</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

**CONFIRM.COMPONENT.TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'uic-confirm',
  templateUrl: './confirm.component.html'
})
export class AppConfirmComponent {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AppConfirmComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) { }
}
```

**CONFIRM.SERVICE.TS**

```
interface ConfirmData {
  title?: string;
  message?: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class AppConfirmService {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }
  public confirm(data: ConfirmData = {}): Observable<boolean> {
    data.title = data.title || '';
    data.message = data.message || '';
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AppConfirmComponent>;
    dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AppConfirmComponent, {
      width: '380px',
      disableClose: true,
      data: { title: data.title, message: data.message }
    });
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
}
```

**SEARCH.COMPONENT.TS** Where I gonna call this Service

```
    deleteDistribution(row) {
      this.confirmService.confirm({message: 'Do you want to delete all or delete single one?'})
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
        this.confirmService
            .confirm({message: `Are you sure you want to delete all?`})
            .subscribe((res) => {
               if (res) {
                // do something
               }
            });
        } else {
          // choose to delete one, go somewhere else
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the solution. By using angular interpolation to display the message. You can do the same for the button text:

```
<button type="button" color="secondary" mat-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close(false)">{{data.actionYesLabel}}</button>
<button type="button" color="secondary" mat-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close(false)">{{data.actionNoLabel}}</button>
```

Adjust your confirm method to pass the buttons label values:

```
 public confirm(data: ConfirmData = {}): Observable<boolean> {
    data.title = data.title || '';
    data.message = data.message || '';
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AppConfirmComponent>;
    dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AppConfirmComponent, {
      width: '380px',
      disableClose: true,
      data: { title: data.title, message: data.message, actionNoLabel: data.actionNoLabel, actionYesLabel: data.actionYesLabel }
    });
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
```

And then pass the button label values when calling the confirm method:

```
this.confirmService.confirm({message: 'Do you want to delete all or delete single one?', actionYesLabel: 'yes', actionNoLabel: 'no'})
```

Each time you call the confirm method you can pass new labels for your action buttons.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does helps. Thank you for the answer.
Made a little adjustment to make this new properties optional with a default text.
I'll leave it here in case anyone are looking for something similar.
`labelAccept?: string;
 labelDecline?: string;`

And then on the **confirm** method:
`data.labelAccept = data.labelAccept || 'YES';
 data.labelDecline = data.labelDecline || 'NO';`

Comment: Great! Naming is up to you.